# Interfacing Directly with the GPIO Peripheral on The Nvidia TX1 and TX2

Tags: raspberry-pi, datasheet

On the RaspberryPi’s there is a few libraries like [pigpio](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio) and [WiringPI](http://wiringpi.com/) that interface directly with the GPIO peripherals by writing directly to the register addresses.

This is particularly useful for hardware based I2C and PWM, where the clock cycle is directly managed by the chip crystals and not by the OS itself.

Is there any library like this for TX1 and/or TX2?

Finding the datasheet RaspberryPi Broadcom CPU is not difficult.  I've been looking for half a day for the datasheet of the TX1 CPU and have not been able to find it.  Is this be design?

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation to help you. Most of it is located on the [Jetson download center.](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads)

Furthermore, [this website](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/) was a lot of use to me. Additional (partially implemented) example: [here](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Gpio-int-test.c).
You will need an Nvidia developer account for the first link, but it is free and absolutely worth it. Lastly if you cannot get something working, ask on the Nvidia development forum.  They are always there to help and mostly give you an answer within a week.